# walk through tree functionally

Tags: clojure, tree, functional-programming

I'm try to writemy own "walk through tree" function, but I'm new in FP

I've wrote these function and it works nice, but it looks ugly

```
(defrecord Tree [value left right])
(defn depth_walk_tree
    [tree functor]
        (let [item (functor (:value tree))]
            (let [leftlst 
                    (if (:left tree) 
                        (cons item (depth_walk_tree (:left tree) functor)) 
                        (list item))
                 ]
                    (if (:right tree)
                        (concat 
                            leftlst 
                            (depth_walk_tree (:right tree) functor)) 
                        leftlst))))

(def tree (Tree. 1 (Tree. 2 (Tree. 0 nil nil) (Tree. 90 nil nil)) (Tree. 3 nil (Tree. 10 nil nil)) ))
    (println (depth_walk_tree tree #(+ % 1) ))
```

Programs answer is

```
(2 3 1 91 4 11); is Ok
```

Can anyone advise me how make it beauty?

PS Sorry for my writing mistakes. English in not my native language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a bit more functional, IMHO:

```
(defn depth_walk_tree [tree functor]
  (concat
    (list (functor (:value tree)))
    (if (:left  tree) (depth_walk_tree (:left  tree) functor))
    (if (:right tree) (depth_walk_tree (:right tree) functor))))
```

And it preserves the original result, too:

```
(depth_walk_tree tree inc)
=> (2 3 1 91 4 11)
```

Comment: so pure! I didn't know that concat passes 'nil' value. Thank you.

Comment: Functional programming is all about simplicity and elegance :)

Comment: How would you avoid the Stack Overflow that would be caused by the non tail-call recursion?

Comment: @event_jr by converting the above to a tail recursion, of course :P . But that's beyond the point, OP was asking for an idiomatic, _beautiful_ solution, the tail-recursive version would be a bit harder to understand for a beginner. This is not a question about efficiency, and I doubt OP is going to define trees so big that cause a stack overflow, this is a learning exercise. Premature optimization is the root of all evil...